error CS0433: The type 'List<T>' exists in both 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
I am working on reversing the app built by Unity 2019.4.15f1 and I am using same version of Unity.
Using the AssetRipper tool, I get the project structure and asset files. But When I build the project on Unity, I get the some issues following as:

Most of issues are:

Assets\Plugins\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(4,12):
error CS0433: The type 'RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute' exists in both
'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and
'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

I saw the several articles and they said remove Unity.Compat.dll and Unity.Tasks.dll inside of Assets/Parse/Plugins. But I don't have these folders (Assets/Parse/Plugins).

As you can see these two files are in Assets/Plugins/ so I removed it. But the issues didn't be solved. I can't do anything. Please help me.

Most if not all those DLL files should not be a part of your project. They are what Unity will provide as part of the runtime already, and therefor your have the conflicts you're seeing.
